# Gwtquery: set an int value to a sliderbar

Tags: java, gwt, slider, gwtquery

I've a slider-bar created by gwtquery in the following manner:

```
slider = $(panelPpal).as(Ui).slider(sliderOptions);
```

I'm trying to set programmatically an int value to that slider. Then I'm issuing:

```
slider.value(someValue);
slider.intValues(someValue);
```

But none of this is working (perhaps, internally the slider is changing its value, but graphically I don't see any change).

Do anybody know if there is an alternate way, something like a workaround? What I'm thinking about is doing something like:

```
$(slider > 'grabButton').left(calculatedValue);
```

But IMO this is a little sloppy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After some research, that was an issue concerning to GWT DevMode. I get an exception when gwt-query invokes the invoke('value',value), that method expects an object, but I'm issuing an Integer which I'm obligued to, due to the signature of setValue(int value). Thanks anyway.